# How to order a HasMany collection by a child property with Fluent NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, mapping, sql-order-by

I am using Fluent NHibernate to map the following classes:

```
public abstract class DomainObject
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeRule
{
    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
    public virtual RuleTypeId RuleTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class Station : DomainObject
{
    public virtual IList<AttributeRule> AttributeRules { get; set; }

    public Station()
    {
        AttributeRules = new List<AttributeRule>();
    }
}
```

My Fluent NHibernate mappings look like this:

```
    public class AttributeMap : ClassMap<Attribute>
    {
        public AttributeMap()
        {
            Id(o => o.Id);
            Map(o => o.Name);
        }
    }

    public class AttributeRuleMap : ClassMap<AttributeRule>
    {
        public AttributeRuleMap()
        {
            Id(o => o.Id);
            Map(o => o.RuleTypeId);
            References(o => o.Attribute).Fetch.Join();
            References(o => o.Station);
        }
    }

    public class StationMap : ClassMap<Station>
    {
        public StationMap()
        {
            Id(o => o.Id);
            HasMany(o => o.AttributeRules).Inverse();
        }
    }
```

I would like to order the AttributeRules list on Station by the Attribute.Name property, but doing the following does not work:

```
   HasMany(o => o.AttributeRules).Inverse().OrderBy("Attribute.Name");
```

I have not found a way to do this yet in the mappings. I could create a IQuery or ICriteria to do this for me, but ideally I would just like to have the AttributeRules list sorted when I ask for it.

Any advice on how to do this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I think the OrderBy-method takes in the string that it inserts to the generated SQL-clause. So just doing

```
HasMany(o => o.AttributeRules).Inverse().OrderBy("Name");
```

Where the "Name" is the name of the column that contains Attribute's name. It should be in the column list because Attribute is joined to the AttributeRule.

Did you solve this other way? Please share.

Comment: The string that it generates contains the table alias, so that's a no-go